# The "componentType" configuration parameter is required for the "" component

Tags: magento, magento2.4

I created a custom module. My module adds the custom attribute to product. Now when I try to add New Product in Magento 2.4.4 , I am getting The **"componentType" configuration parameter is required for the "" component.** error

Here is My code for InstallData.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
 
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
 
    private $eavSetupFactory;
 
    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }
 
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function install(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    ) {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
        'mcwarehouse',
        [
            'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            'label' => 'Warehouse',
            'input' => 'select',
            'source' => \Vendor\Module\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Warehouse::class,
            'backend_model' =>\Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\ArrayBackend::class,
            'required' => false,
            'sort_order' => 50,
            'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
            'group' => 'Product Details',
            'is_used_in_grid' => true,
            'is_visible_in_grid' => false,
            'is_filterable_in_grid' => false
        ]
        );
    }
}
```

The error I got is

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): The "componentType" configuration parameter is required for the "" component.
```